# Sending Complete Vector from Python Client to Java Server

Tags: java, python, sockets, matrix, flatten

I am developing an application that handles some medical image data in Python (nibabel library) and sends the data to a processing server in Java (TCP socket), which is so much faster than the same Python implementation.

In this sense, I am trying to send a 3D matrix (271x271x221) from Python to Java:

```
sock.sendall("Input " + str(input_matrix.flatten()).strip('[]') + "\n")
```

But the problem is that Python shortens the flatten matrix when casting the matrix to string, like that:

```
print input_matrix.flatten()

   [12 12 12 ..., 12 12 12]
```

So the Java server receives:

```
Server is open!
Connection successful
   Waiting for data...
      Received: Input 12 12 12 ..., 12 12 12
```

Thus, I cannot reconstruct the matrix in the Java server.

How can I send all the data without using a loop (a loop will be very slow in processing the complete 3D matrix) in the Python client?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `str` on the `nibabel` vector type tries to meddle and shorten the output as the vector is huge.

Ive not used nibabel, but normally the `repr` function should not shorten it - now, nibabel may have overriden this function for their vector class.

The better thing to do it not use str nor repr - but to make your own string.

`",".join(input_matrix.flatten())`
gives you the whole vectors with commas in between every element.

Comment: I have tried this, but now I obtain another error related to the casting in `.join`: `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, numpy.int16 found`. How can I solve this? Thank you AJK!

Comment: ','.join(str(x) for x in input_matrix.flatten())

Comment: Thank you! The last one worked very well. By the way, is there any equivalent line in java?

Comment: Java should have an equivalent ... but Im not well versed with it. Also, it'd depend on the class you use - simple array, arraylist, etc. Searching for it on google should give you something